# How to check condition in then block using SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to check

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    table 
WHERE
    CASE
       WHEN startdate IS NULL 
          THEN updatedon >= enddate 
          ELSE updatedon BETWEEN startdate AND enddate
```

I'm getting error in THEN block in the condition ">".

Comment: A CASE WHEN returns a value. Never a condition. It's like a switch.  But you could let it return a value, and the check on that.  Btw, it can contain multiple `WHEN ... THEN`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Boolean logic instead of `case` expression :

```
select *
from table t
where (startdate is null and updatedon >= enddate) or
      (startdate is not null and (updatedon >= startdate and updatedon <= enddate)
      );
```

Comment: why don't you use `BETWEEN` instead of the last `AND` clause?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have a condition as a result for CASE, try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM _table
WHERE startdate IS NULL
      AND updatedon >= enddate
      OR startdate IS NOT NULL
      AND updatedon BETWEEN startdate AND enddate;
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the other answers, this would give the expected result:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE (
   (startdate IS NOT NULL AND updatedon BETWEEN startdate AND enddate) 
   OR (startdate IS NULL AND updatedon >= enddate)
);
```

But if you still would like to using a CASE WHEN, then it could look like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE 
  (CASE 
   WHEN startdate IS NOT NULL AND updatedon BETWEEN startdate AND enddate THEN 1
   WHEN startdate IS NULL AND updatedon >= enddate THEN 2
   ELSE 0
   END) > 0
```

Note that the CASE WHEN returns a value.

But that would just over-complicate the SQL. And probably be less performant.
Since it'll be harder for the query optimizer to find the fastest execution plan.

Answer (score 0):

In the code below, if `startdate` isn't `NULL` then `updatedon BETWEEN startdate AND enddate` will be used. Else - `updatedon BETWEEN enddate AND '31-12-9999'`, where `'31-12-9999'` is equivalent of a `date` type max value, so, it's equal to `updatedon >= enddate`.

```
SELECT *
FROM _table
WHERE updatedon BETWEEN ISNULL(startdate, enddate) AND CASE
                                                           WHEN startdate IS NULL
                                                           THEN DATEFROMPARTS(9999, 12, 31)
                                                           ELSE enddate
                                                       END;
```